# Responsys - How to field merge multiple rows on one column using RPL?

Tags: responsys

Basically, I need to field merge a field in a certain table. Let's say `TableA.Col1`.
The syntax `${TableA.Col1}` works perfectly. However, it only shows the first row of data in the table, whereas, I need to field merge the second row of the data as well.
Any suggestions?

I am trying like an array call `${TableA.Col1[0]}` or `${TableA.Col1[1]}` but no luck.

Hope to meet some Responsys guru here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<#data>` directive to pull multiple records from a supplemental table.  Interpolations with `Table.Column` syntax are designed for 1->1 relationships so will only pull the 1st record.